# How to add a path to system $PATH for all users's non-login shell for debian

Tags: debian, environment-variables, path

After installing some programs in `/opt/xxx/bin`, I want to add `/opt/xxx/bin` to system `$PATH` for all users's non-login shell. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Debian and other systems that use PAM (which is most of them nowadays), you can set environment variables (including `PATH`) in `/etc/environment`. This will work for any login method that uses the [`pam_env`](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) module (either in the `auth` section or in the `session` section); on Debian that should be all of them (at least the ones that provide ways to log in and run commands).

Answer (score 2):

The default path could be set in `/etc/profile` like Joe said but also in `$HOME/.profile`. I also have plenty of packages i compiled on my own (with the common procedure `./configure --prefix=/opt/<name>`) installed in `/opt`. To execute the binaries in `/opt/<name>/bin` without any additional effort I added

```
OPTDIR=/opt

for i in $OPTDIR/* ; do
    BINDIR=$i/bin
    if [ -d $BINDIR ] ; then
        if [ -z $PATH ] ; then
            PATH=$BINDIR
        else
            PATH=$BINDIR:$PATH
        fi
    fi
done

export PATH
```

to my `$HOME/.profile` which in your case would be `/etc/profile`. Now even if i install packages under `/opt` in the future i don't have to worry about accessing the related binaries in `/opt/.*/bin` since the path is automatically added to `$PATH`.

Because the additional software is not necessary stable i prefer `$HOME/.profile` over `/etc/profile`.

---

A small remark: `/etc/.profile` respectively `$HOME/profile` is not executed by your default shell but by `dash`. A lightweight variant of `bash` which reduces the load during the boot process.

Comment: Neither `/etc/profile` nor `~/.profile` is not executed by non-login shell.

Comment: You are right, my answer is not fully related to your question. I just described what i did to get things running. If you aren't using X my approach does what you want since every non-login shell is a child-process of the login-shell. If you are using X you can source the little script i have posted in the init file of your display manager (in most cases `Xsession`). Now every child process of the display manager have the defined `$PATH` variable. In the described two cases my approach definitely works and you can access every binaries under `/opt/.*/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the most excellent answer on serverfault by [Gilles](http://stackexchange.com/users/164368/gilles):

[How set PATH for all users in Debian?](https://serverfault.com/a/166403/161937)

> The first place where PATH is set is `/etc/login.defs`. There's a setting for root and a setting for everyone else.
>
> Another place where you can define environment variables is `/etc/environment`. These settings will apply to everyone (you can't write arbitrary shell code there).
>
> A third place where you can define environment variables is `/etc/profile`. There you can write arbitrary shell code. If you want a user-specific setting, there is the corresponding per-user file `~www-data/.profile`.  But this will only apply to console interactive logins; in particular it won't apply to cron jobs unless they explicitly source `/etc/profile`.
>
> If you only need that `PATH` setting in a user crontab, you can write it at the beginning of the crontab. Note that you need the full list (`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/zend/bin`), you can't use a variable substitution (`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin` won't work there).

Answer (score 0):

The default path can be set in /etc/profile

But I was just looking on my Ubuntu system, and it's set in /etc/environment

Comment: `/etc/profile` is not executed by non-login shell.